# После добавления зависимостей в Андроид Студио выдает ошибку - Failed to parse XML

Tags: java, android-studio

Вот код:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    }

    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:29.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'

    //QR Code Scanner and Generator
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0@aar'

    //Download images from API
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:29.0.0'

    }
```

После добавления зависимостей студия выдает ошибку:

> Failed to parse XML in D:\Androidprojects\MyApplication\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя использовать в одном проекте support и androidx библиотеки одновременно. Либо одно, либо другое. Androidx пришел на смену support, и это сравнимо с тем, чтобы подключить две разные версии одной библиотеки. Уберите support, поправьте код на использование androidx если использовали что-то из support и все должно заработать